# Cordova 9, how to copy entire directory from plugin to res or src?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova9

I've updated from Cordova 6 to Cordova 9 trying to keep all the plugins,

but I'm struggling with copying directories from plugins with plugin.xml, because it seems not work

In other words, the tag :

```
<source-file src="src/android/res/someVeryImportantSrcDir" target-dir="java/com/co/jp/" />
```

doesn't work anymore..

I've also read about this in doc at [this section](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/it/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html) but nothing seems to talk about moving directory with source-file tags.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova Plugin alternate to <source-file> tag to copy entire directory contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042385/cordova-plugin-alternate-to-source-file-tag-to-copy-entire-directory-contents)

Comment: Have you removed and readded the cordova-android platform after the upgrade?

Comment: No, but, if I remove my platform data, I'd remove also the customizations inside it. How can I upgrade my cordova-android platform?